# How to build scalable email communication system as part of Application development?

Tags: .net, email, azure, web-applications

We are developing enterprise application that is hosted in Microsoft Azure cloud platform. When we have a deal with any enterprise company, they buy licences for relatively high amount of users. (min 5K employee per our customer)

Our application is often needing to send an email to certain population of a customer.
As the number of customer(tenant) we have shall grow over time, number of emails that our system supposed to send shall increase gradually.

The current solution we have has started to hit some limit since we are using one of email providers (such as Gmail, office365) SMTP servers to distribute the emails to our clients. Since those provider has some limitation interms of number of sent emails per day, we started to hit the limit recently. To overcome this issue we started to send the emails through different email account.
Obviously creating new email account is not a good solution.

What we want is to have centric email system which will serve to all our tenants without any issue. The potential solution should also be ready for scale-out scenario when we need to send a million email if we have million end-user across all tenants, we should not need to change the code, instead, we can just increase instance of email system app.

I believe the application like Facebook or twitter is keep sending more than 1M email a day. How do you think they are managing these amount of email communication ? Is there any article that I can learn something from when we are building this system. Or any approach you can suggest.

Thanks in advance.

P.S : Hopefully I am writing this question to correct StackOverFlow community.

Comment: there's no real right answer, since this is opinion-based. There are several 3rd-party email vendors that solve this problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the issue of sending large number of emails, another thing you would need to worry about is sending emails that don't get blocked by recipient's mail servers (this normally happens when you host your mail servers in the cloud).

I would recommend looking into `SendGrid`. They have special plans for Azure and AFAIK there's no limit on the number of emails sent out daily (you just pick a plan based on your email requirements). You can learn more about them here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/partners/sendgrid/sendgrid-azure/.

Comment: since we are signing a SaaS agreement with our client, there are two sides of the agreement. Our Customer and us. So it is really hard to add additonal party to the software agreement to convince our customer to sign the deal. What if we want to develop in house solution ?

Comment: @telli Your SaaS agreement will simply be (I'm presuming!) to put an email into someone's inbox. You have got a much higher chance of that happening by using somebody who is specialised in doing that. A singular Azure server spitting out email will very likely get filtered. A globally recognised company, who understands the nuances of actually delivering email to inboxes is much more likely to keep you inside of your SaaS agreement.

Answer (score 0):

SendGrid is a great option and I have used it before to send millions of emails. There are other options as well like Mandrill, Mailgun, Amazon SES, etc.

Depends a little bit on what sort of features you want. Some can help processing inbound emails as well. Some have tools to template outbound emails or do A/B testing, track click & open rates, etc

This website lists several options but SendGrid is probably the leader.
http://alternativeto.net/software/sendgrid/

Comment: Hi,  I replied to @gaurav-mantri reply. Same reply is also valid for you response.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to develop your own email solution. I would initially advise to sign up to an email provider - such as Sendgrid / Amazon SES - Simply because it gets you running very quickly, with a few lines of code.

Once that is running and working as expected, you could start to develop your own solution, based on what you learn from using that service.

At that point you can slowly migrate users away from the email service and onto your own solution.

It isn't difficult to build a solution to send a million emails (well...) What is difficult is ensuring that your mail is delivered to an inbox. If there was an easy way to do this, spammers would be doing it already.

So while you can use DKIM etc to provide extra verification the thing that you won't have, that you primarily rely on bulk providers for is their reputation as being a bulk provider.

This is how facebook et al. Manage to run their own services, because they are trusted by blacklisting companies, and not too many people flag their messages as spam.

Have a gradual ramp up, pay very close attention to rebounds (ensuring you don't send to those addresses again) personalise the message with the name of the user. Use multiple ip addresses to send from.

Ultimately, configuring your own bulk email service is hard and time consuming. To the extent that you could very quickly need a permanent member of staff keeping the whole thing running smoothly (and keeping you off blacklists)

Save yourself a lot of headache and pay someone who's business it is to do this stuff well.