# Point IP Address to Azure Resource Group Web App

Tags: azure, dns, azure-resource-manager, static-ip-address

I am playing around with setting up a Web App in an Azure Resource Group, and I'm using a personal domain of mine (that I'm not currently using for anything) to learn and play: woodswild.com.

I've got the Web App all set up at http://woodswild.azurewebsites.net. There's nothing there right now except Azure's "Coming Soon" screen, and that's fine.  I've also logged into GoDaddy and added this A Host Record:

```
Host             Points To
----             -------------
 @               23.99.206.151
```

And a few CName Records:

```
Host             Points To:
------------     ------------------------------------------
www              woodswild.azurewebsites.net
awverify.www     awverify.woodswild.azurewebsites.net
awverify         awverify.woodswild.azurewebsites.net
```

And then in the Azure Portal UI, I've added the following in the 'Bring External Domains' section of the Web App:

[image]

The result is that I can now browse to http://www.woodswild.com, and it resolves! I get the Azure "Coming Soon" message.

So now my question is:  Is it possible to also browse to http://23.99.206.151 and have that also resolve to woodswild.azurewebsites.net?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much easier one -

No.

Because all that IP address is is the load balancer out in front of Azure Web App, it could be serving a thousand different websites. Azure filters which request goes where by inspecting the headers. i.e. what was typed in the browser.

Comment: Ok, so IS there any way to have a single IP that is dedicated to this web app? Or to awverify.woodswild.azurewebsites.net?  23.99.206.151 is not the Static IP created when I added a Public IP Address to the Resource Group, made it static, and associated it to the Network Interface.  It's the IP I get back when I do this:  Resolve-DnsName (Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName TestRG1 -Name woodswild).EnabledHostNames[0]

Comment: The only thing you can have a static IP for within Azure is a VM, so the only way you could - conceivably - make that work would be to either host it on a VM, or have a VM redirect the traffic for you. Either way it is going to get quite a bit more complex - out of curiosity, why do you want / need it?

Comment: "out of curiosity, why do you want / need it?"  Yeah, a fair question.  And the answer is: I am trying to find out if doing a Reverse IP Lookup is even possible using Azure Resource Groups. I *know* they are possible using the standard Cloud VM's.  Not sure about the ARM model, and I can't find ANYTHING via google.  I'm leaning towards "No, it's not possible", but I thought I would test by setting up a full domain/website and then trying it. And... the reason I need to know if a Reverse IP is even possible is because we hope to host a mail server.

Comment: That's probably worth a whole different question, but ultimately a very bad idea (I've got an answer about it somewhere) You're far far better sending mail through a bulk service, if you want any chance of landing them in users inboxes anyway

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. We're doing it successfully right now with our own MailEnable server hosted at Rack Space.  But we are trying to get off Rack Space and move to Azure.  The hope was to minimize change in code and to migrate the existing structure into a Resource Group.  But I think I now have enough knowledge and documentation to go back to my boss and say, "No, I can say with certainty that this plan will NOT work."  This question, and my other one, were designed to flush all this out.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to have helped! - My old answers are  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779829/how-to-build-scalable-email-communication-system-as-part-of-application-developm/33784144#33784144) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694978/why-does-amazon-ec2-limit-port-25/34695131#34695131) - just incase they're useful

Comment: I read those those another answers.  Thanks.  Question.  You said in an earlier comment: "The only thing you can have a static IP for within Azure is a VM".  Will this work with a VM inside the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) model?  Or only in the now legacy Azure Service Management model?  We have a domain up and running that sends over 100k emails per month, and we don't have any problems with being blacklisted.  We want to migrate that server from RackSpace to Azure, but we need to be sure that a Reverse IP lookup is possible so we don't get black listed.

Comment: You can certainly create a reverse look up for an IP on an Azure machine - though it is a little complicated, I've a post about that somewhere too! - You can't create a static IP via templates, but I think they work with everything else (you can still do reverse lookup with dynamic IPs though)

Comment: Ok, thanks!  Could I burden you to see my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229592/what-dns-name-label-should-i-give-my-azure-virtual-machine